# convert variable to uppercase and reference dynamically in shell script

Tags: shell, circleci

I'm using a shell script with Circle CI. I'm trying to dynamically reference an environment variable based on my Circle CI branch name. The variable name for my testing branch is `DIRCHANGE_UN` but it will be different for each branch. I also need to convert the branch name to uppercase.

I want to concatenate and reference `CIRCLE_BRANCH + _UN`

What I have right now

```
#!/bin/sh
set -ex
echo "$CIRCLE_BRANCH"
BRANCH_UPPER="$(echo ${CIRCLE_BRANCH} | tr 'a-z' 'A-Z')"
echo $BRANCH_UPPER
echo "$BRANCH_UPPER"
UN="$(echo "${BRANCH_UPPER}_UN")"
echo $UN
echo ${!UN}
```

The log from CircleCI:

```
+ echo dirchange
dirchange
+ echo dirchange
+ tr a-z A-Z
+ BRANCH_UPPER=DIRCHANGE
+ echo DIRCHANGE
DIRCHANGE
+ echo DIRCHANGE
DIRCHANGE
+ echo DIRCHANGE_UN
+ UN=DIRCHANGE_UN
+ echo DIRCHANGE_UN
DIRCHANGE_UN
./dx-utils/deploy-with-tests.sh: 9: ./dx-utils/deploy-with-tests.sh: Bad substitution
```

I'm assuming it's obvious, but I'm new to shell scripts so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

POSIX shell doesn't provide any support for indirect parameter expansion; `${!...}` is a `bash` extension. You'll have to use `eval`, which means making *very* sure that you know what the contents of `UN` are beforehand.

```
expr "$UN" : '[A-Z_][A-Z_]*' && eval 'echo "$UN"'
```

`expr` ensurs that the value of `UN` consists of nothing but uppercase letters and `_` before attempting to evaluate the command produced by its expansion, so that there are no surprises.

Comment: Thanks, I'm still a little unclear on how this should work, how would I log out the value of the concatenated variable name?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
CIRCLE_BRANCH="login"
BRANCH_UPPER="$(echo ${CIRCLE_BRANCH} | tr 'a-z' 'A-Z')"
LOGIN_UN=john
UN=$(set | grep "^${BRANCH_UPPER}_UN="| cut -d= -f2-)
echo "$UN"
```

Please use lowercase variable names.